# avoid git merge conflicts due to per-user settings in Makefile

Tags: git, makefile, merge-conflict-resolution

My git-managed project runs on different hosts.
The project's dependencies (include directories, third-party libraries; but not enough of them to warrant the sledgehammer of autoconf) are in a different place on each host.
So the project's makefile includes settings that differ on each host.  For example:

```
FST_DIR=/usr/local/include
FST_DIR=/home/user12345/openFST/src/include
FST_DIR=/home/user67890/tmp/include
```

What's a good way to stop these differences from constantly causing conflicts when I `git merge`?  Just move those settings into their own file, included by the makefile, ignored by git?  (If so, what happens the first time a newbie tries to make, and the file is missing?)

(Similar problems might exist without git or makefiles.  For example, a Visual Studio project, developed on several PCs each with its own configuration.)

Comment: Since it's user specific, it's better to stored such setting locally (or in user profile), e.g. environment variable.  Then makefile could check if it's present and valid, otherwise fallback to default location, if it still fails, return error message to ask user to configure it (of course, provide  instructions as well).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, move the config to an include makefile that is ignored by git.

You can get make to prompt the user for the values needed in the file when it doesn't exist to handle the "new user" problem.

Something like this.

```
include config.mk

config.mk:
        @echo 'Configuration file $@ not found. Creating...'
        @printf 'Value to set for FST_DIR: '; IFS= read -r dir && [ -n "$$dir" ] && printf 'FST_DIR=%s\n' "$$dir" > $@
```